# LocalStorage and Cache clear at initial load in nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, local-storage

In our project we need to give continuous updates, after updating the system, users need to clear their cache and localStorage data manually so that they can use the updates.

Is there any way to deal with the problem, where after updates all the cache will be cleared for once when the user comes to the site? the project is built upon Nextjs.

Comment: @jmvcollaborator what about the cache?

Comment: When to call it? Like, for example, a version called v1.1 is already being used by a user. We updated the system from v1.1 to v1.2, whereas we want the user should use the system as a fresh start. For that, we need to clear their old cached data and localStorage data. Previously our users manually removed all the data. But now we want to make it for user friendly so that after the update, whenever the user comes to the site, all the cached and stored data will be cleared.

Comment: browser cache ? it is unrelated to local storage

Comment: Then save the version in local storage to know if it must be cleared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a setting which takes the version ID, compare it, if different then clear local storage and set the newer version on local storage, something like this code should work.

```
  var version = "v1.2";
  var storageversion = localStorage.getItem("version");
  if (storageversion !== version) {    
    localStorage.clear();
    localStorage.setItem("version", version);
  }
```

Comment: Nice. It will work for sure.

Answer (score 0):

you may use the function of the localstorage as:

```
localstorage.removeItem(contents in localstorage to be removed);
```